# How to split a wav file on WP8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, split, wav

Is there a way to split a wav file in C# WP8? I'd like to save a sample of a wav file, starting at, for example, 00:30 and ending at 00:40.

Maybe using some kind of stream or buffer, but then I'd have to know when to start/finish copying the stream to another wav file.

How can I do this?

Comment: How are you reading the file? NAudio or something? (Or haven't you got that far?)

Comment: I've found an example out there that uses xaudio2 and c++, but it just gives me the option to play/pause. I'll try merging it with Oliver's sample code.

Comment: Ok, well I was going to suggest creating your own implementation if your interested? It's quite easy really.

Comment: Well, I could use a sample code to play that audio sample before cropping, just for confirmation. Can you help?

Comment: Yes I can, I've made class for reading a vast number of formats of Wav files, so cropping is simply selecting samples from X to Y...I'll post an answer if your still interested?

Comment: Of course, can you kindly post it? (or a link). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a wav file's header can vary from 44 (standard) to over 100 bytes, you'll need to first determine the exact size of the header and also read important meta information before you can start chopping up your wav file(s).

So you need to know the following meta data about your wav file(s),

- Sample rate,
- Bit depth,
- Channel count,
- Audio data format (whether samples are PCM or Floating-Point)
- Header size.

Before continuing, I'd recommend reading the [format of a wav file header](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/) first so you'll have a better idea of what the code is doing.

So first we need to get our meta info,

```
private void ReadMetaData(FileStream stream, out bool isFloatinfPoint, out int channelCount, out int sampleRate, out int bitDepth, out int headerSize)
{
    var headerBytes = new byte[200];

    // Read header bytes.
    stream.Position = 0;
    stream.Read(headerBytes, 0, 200);

    headerSize = new string(Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(headerBytes)).IndexOf("data") + 8;
    isFloatinfPoint = BitConverter.ToUInt16(new byte[] { headerBytes[20], headerBytes[21] }, 0) == 3 ? true : false;
    channelCount = BitConverter.ToUInt16(new byte[] { headerBytes[22] , headerBytes[23] }, 0);
    sampleRate = (int)BitConverter.ToUInt32(new byte[] { headerBytes[24], headerBytes[25], headerBytes[26], headerBytes[27] }, 0);
    bitDepth = BitConverter.ToUInt16(new byte[] { headerBytes[34], headerBytes[35] }, 0);
}
```

Once we have this data we can then calculate where we need to start and stop reading our file. To calculate the start and end indexes we do,

```
var startIndex = (int)(start.TotalSeconds * sampleRate * byteDepth * channelCount);
var endIndex = (int)(end.TotalSeconds * sampleRate * byteDepth * channelCount);
```

`start` & `end` would be a `TimeSpan` indicating when to start and stop cropping.

We can now read the bytes from our file using our newly calculated info, if you're using a `FileStream` you would do the following,

```
var newBytes = new byte[endIndex - startIndex];

myStream.Position = headerSize + startIndex; // Add headerSize to position to make sure we don't read the header.
myStream.Read(newBytes, 0, newBytes.Length);
```

The all you have to do is write a wav header to the destination file along with the newly extracted audio. So, putting this altogether you should end up with something like this,

```
private void CropWavFile(string inputFilePath, string outputFilePath, TimeSpan start, TimeSpan end)
{
    var stream = new FileStream(inputFilePath, FileMode.Open);
    var newStream = new FileStream(outputFilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    var isFloatingPoint = false;
    var sampleRate = 0;
    var bitDepth = 0;
    var channelCount = 0;
    var headerSize = 0;

    // Get meta info
    ReadMetaData(stream, out isFloatingPoint, out channelCount, out sampleRate, out bitDepth, out headerSize);

    // Calculate where we need to start and stop reading.
    var startIndex = (int)(start.TotalSeconds * sampleRate * (bitDepth / 8) * channelCount);
    var endIndex = (int)(end.TotalSeconds * sampleRate * (bitDepth / 8) * channelCount);
    var bytesCount = endIndex - startIndex;
    var newBytes = new byte[bytesCount];

    // Read audio data.
    stream.Position = startIndex + headerSize;
    stream.Read(newBytes, 0, bytesCount);

    // Write the wav header and our newly extracted audio to the new wav file.
    WriteMetaData(newStream, isFloatingPoint, (ushort)channelCount, (ushort)bitDepth, sampleRate, newBytes.Length / (bitDepth / 8));
    newStream.Write(newBytes, 0, newBytes.Length);

    stream.Dispose();
    newStream.Dispose();
}

private void WriteMetaData(FileStream stream, bool isFloatingPoint, ushort channels, ushort bitDepth, int sampleRate, int totalSampleCount)
{
    stream.Position = 0;

    // RIFF header.
    // Chunk ID.
    stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("RIFF"), 0, 4);

    // Chunk size.
    stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(((bitDepth / 8) * totalSampleCount) + 36), 0, 4);

    // Format.
    stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("WAVE"), 0, 4);



    // Sub-chunk 1.
    // Sub-chunk 1 ID.
    stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("fmt "), 0, 4);

    // Sub-chunk 1 size.
    stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(16), 0, 4);

    // Audio format (floating point (3) or PCM (1)). Any other format indicates compression.
    stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)(isFloatingPoint ? 3 : 1)), 0, 2);

    // Channels.
    stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(channels), 0, 2);

    // Sample rate.
    stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(sampleRate), 0, 4);

    // Bytes rate.
    stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(sampleRate * channels * (bitDepth / 8)), 0, 4);

    // Block align.
    stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)channels * (bitDepth / 8)), 0, 2);

    // Bits per sample.
    stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(bitDepth), 0, 2);



    // Sub-chunk 2.
    // Sub-chunk 2 ID.
    stream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("data"), 0, 4);

    // Sub-chunk 2 size.
    stream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes((bitDepth / 8) * totalSampleCount), 0, 4);
}

private void ReadMetaData(FileStream stream, out bool isFloatinfPoint, out int channelCount, out int sampleRate, out int bitDepth, out int headerSize)
{
    var headerBytes = new byte[200];

    // Read header bytes.
    stream.Position = 0;
    stream.Read(headerBytes, 0, 200);

    headerSize = new string(Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(headerBytes)).IndexOf("data") + 8;
    isFloatinfPoint = BitConverter.ToUInt16(new byte[] { headerBytes[20], headerBytes[21] }, 0) == 3 ? true : false;
    channelCount = BitConverter.ToUInt16(new byte[] { headerBytes[22] , headerBytes[23] }, 0);
    sampleRate = (int)BitConverter.ToUInt32(new byte[] { headerBytes[24], headerBytes[25], headerBytes[26], headerBytes[27] }, 0);
    bitDepth = BitConverter.ToUInt16(new byte[] { headerBytes[34], headerBytes[35] }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Well, way more simple now. It just works :) Thank you. Now I just need to figure out a way to create those wavs from my mp3 collection on the phone, but that's another story.

Comment: @user2962761 So you need to convert mp3s to wavs? If so have you tried using [NAudio](https://naudio.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: Yes, it's a good project, but when I try to add a reference via nuget, there's an error: "Could not install package 'NAudio 1.7.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

Comment: @user2962761 Then why don't you just [download](https://naudio.codeplex.com/downloads/get/750342#) the dll and manually add a reference to it?

Comment: I can't beacuse "A reference to a higher version or incompatible assembly cannot be added to the project"

Comment: @user2962761 Right. Before continuing I think it would be best if we moved this conversation to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56441/discussion-between-sam-and-user2962761).

Answer (score 1):

on my blog I posted about this, starting with this post (http://csharp-tricks-en.blogspot.de/2011/03/read-in-wave-files.html) aboud reading a wave file with the next 2 posts building up on this .. hope that helps!
Best
Oliver

Comment: Thank you, what a great post! I will try your code. It's gonna take a while, because I'll try to integrate with xaudio2, c++, directX and I'm not that expert... but I'll report back when I'm done :)

Comment: I had the opportunity to test your code and it also works. Thank you.